# Bash script to execute a Python program

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to write a bash script which can get all the file names from a folder and execute another Python script which takes one file name at a time.

How do I do that?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty simple case for a `for` command.

Answer (score 3):

```
for file in /path/*
do
  python main.py "$file"
done
```